# nicely print out a matrix in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of lists (matrix) in mathematica. I want to print it out nicely, with the max in every row in bold. How to do this?

Or maybe even further, with a circle outside such max, is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `MatrixForm` to print out matrices nicely:

```
data = RandomInteger[100, {5, 5}];

data // MatrixForm
```

yields

[image: MatrixForm image]

You can draw a circle around the maximum in each row as follows:

```
Map[# /. m : Max[#] :> Framed[m, RoundingRadius -> 1000]  &, data] //
  MatrixForm
```

yielding

[image: matrix with circles]

`RoundingRadius -> 1000` uses a ridiculously large parameter to get circles.  You may need to adjust the constant depending upon the scale of your display.

You can change `Framed[m...]` with `Style[m, Bold]` if you prefer bolding.

Comment: I like the `# /. m:Max[#] -> ...` construction. (+1)

Answer (score 8):

**Grid[ ]** gives you fine grain control on the display appearance. For example:

```
g[a_] := Grid[a,
  Background -> {None, {{LightBlue, LightRed}}},
  Dividers -> {False, All},
  ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    MapIndexed[Flatten@{#2, Ordering[#1, -1]} -> {Bold, Red} &, a]}]

g[RandomInteger[100, {10, 7}]]
```

[image]

NB> It'll highlight only one element per row

**Edit**

To highlight every max element, you could do for example:

```
g[a_] := Grid[a,
  Background -> {None, {{LightBlue, LightRed}}},
  Dividers -> {False, All},
  ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Flatten[Tuples[{First@#, Last@#}] & /@ 
       MapIndexed[{#2, Position[#1, Max[#1]]} &, a], 
      1] /. {q_, {r_}} -> ({q, r} -> {Red, Bold})}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, it is going to take me a little while to figure out why your first example only highlights the one element.

Comment: @rcollyer No mystery around that. **Ordering[l,-1]** returns only one element.

Comment: ah, I see. `MapIndexed` returns a list with elements of the form `{row_num, first_max_pos}-> {Bold, Red}`.